# How to add a column to an existing database for f.datetime_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing db(`Posts`) and now I want to add a column to it for a `f.datetime_select`, what commands do I need to run?

```
rails g migration add_datetime_to_posts datetime:string
```

Comment: The column should be of type datetime, not string.

Comment: `rails g migration AddDateTimeSelectToPosts datetime_select:datetime` but what is `datetime_select`? Maybe could you use `created_at` or `updated_at` column instead. Also, you should looking for another name

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `DateTime` is a class in RoR (see [this link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/DateTime.html)), you should give another name to your column, i will call it as `example`.

Now, see you step-by-step:

```
rails g migration add_datetime_to_posts example:datetime # create the migrate, added a example column to Posts, the type is datetime
rails db:migrate # execute all pending migrations
```

After running this commands, you will have the `example` datetime field to your Post resource.

Comment: "datetime its a datatype in Ruby" - no, it's not. DateTime is. Completely different. I agree that the name should be improved (not by changing it to `example`, though). But column name `datetime` should work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

To add column datetime_select run,

```
rails g migration add_datetime_select_to_posts DatetimeSelect:string
```